# Removing objects in a set Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if Javascript sets are indexed. From my experience with other programming languages, they are not usually indexed. I checked by creating a new set in JS and added some values. Then I asked for the index 0 and 1 values but it returned `undefined` so I am assuming they are not indexed.

How do you remove an object from a set in JS?

ex:

```
  var data = new Set();
  data.add({"val1" : [1,2,3]});
  data.add({"val2" : [4,5,6]});
  data.add({"val3" : [7,8,9]});
```

I checked with `data.has({"val1" : [1,2,3]})` but it returned false so I am assuming that line of code is not referring to the same object.

Comment: you are correct - its not the same reference. you have to store that or use a `Map` with a unique key.

Comment: Try searching for the object you want to delete first, then use data.delete() with it.

Comment: What `Set` library are you using?  ES6?  A polyfill?  A third party library? In `Set` libraries that support an object as a value, you will have to supply the EXACT same object (not an equivalent object) in order to find it in the Set.  It doesn't look for an object that has the same properties.  It looks for the exact same object reference (e.g. something that would pass `===`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to an array and remove using the index like this.

```
var data = new Set();
data.add({"val1" : [1,2,3]});
data.add({"val2" : [4,5,6]});
data.add({"val3" : [7,8,9]});

alert(data.size === 3); //true

data.delete([...data][1]); //Remove the middle object

alert(data.size === 2); //true
```

ES6Fiddle here.

http://www.es6fiddle.net/i1nxqwm0/

Please take into account the compatibility table for Set.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Hope this helps.